# javascript if("" != "") not working

Tags: javascript

HTML & PHP

```
<?for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){?>
   <input type='textbox' style="width:100%" name='name[]' id = 'name<?echo $i;?>'>
<?}?>
```

Javascript

```
for(var i=1;i<="?";i++){
       if(document.getElementById('name'+i).value != "")    {
           alert("text_if");
       }else{
           alert("text_else");
       }
}
```

In the textbox don't have value (mean "") so "" != ""

return false alert text_if but it's not working don't alert all.

i try "" == "" it's working why != not working please help me

**Okay it's working now 
but i have loop but i don't know max of element 
because i have function add&del textbox (create element)**

Comment: Have you tried logging (or alerting) what `document.getElementById('name').value` evaluates to? If you're getting no alert at all, perhaps you have a syntax error in your JS. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: What is not working? The code above should alert the `text_else` since the value is an empty string.

Comment: It is much more likely that you are doing something wrong than that a JS engine evaluates `"" != ""` incorrectly.

Comment: If nothing alerts at all, it means your code was never executed or crashed. Did anything show in the console? Also, value will return "" if it wasn't set, so it should work.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket __}__ at the end of your _script_

Answer (score 1):

It works:

http://jsfiddle.net/uyz6fozt/

I just needed to add a closing bracket }.

Change

```
<input type='textbox' style="width:100%" name='name[]' id = 'name' value="ENTERSOMETHINGHEREORREMOVEIT">
```

to

```
<input type='textbox' style="width:100%" name='name[]' id = 'name' value="">
```

and press RUN to see it working.

Answer (score 0):

It's false because the empty strings are equal.

`"" != ""` translates to "an empty string is not equal to an empty string" which is false because they are indeed equal.

```js
if(document.getElementById('name').value != "") {
    alert("text_if");
}else{
    alert("text_else");
}
```

```html
<input type='textbox' style="width:100%" name='name[]' id = 'name'>
```

Notice how the else statement runs here. If it is not running for you, it means you may have placed your javascript in a location where it runs before the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are calling this after the element has loaded - so ensure you wrap it in a function that is only called after the page has fully loaded - or alternatively have the script after the closing body tag (page runs more efficiently this way)

JavaScript can only call elements with IDs that exist in the DOM :)